# how do I show favorites on dialog boxes?

Tags: macos

I thought that originally it appeared on all windows but now it only shows on the finder window.  Can I somehow have this favorites appear for any dialog box?

[image: List item]

Comment: Using OSX 10.11.5 and can see favorites in all dialog boxes like open, save and browse

Comment: huh...thanks for catching that...I thought i was running the latest copy of but apparently not the case cool deal, if you want to put that into an answer I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not running the latest version of **OSX** *i.e. El Capitan 10.11.5 Build 15F34* released 16 May 2016 updating the OS should resolve the issues

As I am running the same and can see favorites in all the dialog boxes.